# Getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.addListener')

Tags: react-native, high-order-component

I am trying to implement HOC for Backhandler. I have 3 component all are wrapped in createBottomTabNavigator, home is one of them. but before implementing backhandling ,HOC showing this error.
[image]

**Component home-**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text,View} from 'react-native';
import updateComponent from './HOC/updateComponent';
class home extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
 render() {
  return (
     <View><Text> HOC</Text></View>
    );
  }
}
export default updateComponent(home);
```

**HOC updateComponent**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const updateComponent = WrappedComponent => {
  class NewComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {

      return <WrappedComponent />;
    }
  }
  return NewComponent;
};
export default updateComponent;
```

Comment: Try `<WrappedComponent {...props} />`

Comment: Thanku, but getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Your `home` component should be capitalized, from [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized):

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div'
>   or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
>   component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
>   capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

Another thing (not sure causing the error but you'll have bugs later on), is that you don't pass the props to the `NewComponent`, which means every time you will wrap a component with `updateComponent` you'll lose all the props.

**Solution:**

1. `home` -> `Home`.
2. `return <WrappedComponent />` --> `return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />`.